# Get the app back ince you delete that app from App requests and activity Facebook Settings

Tags: ios, facebook, settings, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have accidently removed my app from App requests and activity Facebook Settings. Now when i press facebook login in the my third party app. It does nothing. How can i gety the app back in Facebook Setting in App requests and activity settings?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to reset .plist settings.

Comment: Explain clearly what is happening...Are you testing your code in simulator?

Comment: No i am testing my code on device... the problem is not in the iphone device but the problem is in the FB settings.

Comment: I have integrated facebook many time though I am not getting your question clearly. please explain a bit...